# Combining wget and zenity/yad

Tags: bash, shell, sh, wget

I'm trying to provide some kind of a GUI for wget download process by using zenity/yad. I have come up with this:

```
wget http://example.com/ 2>&1 | \
sed -u 's/^[a-zA-Z\-].*//; s/.* \{1,2\}\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)%.*/\1\n#Downloading... \1%/; s/^20[0-9][0-9].*/#Done./' | \
zenity --progress --percentage=0 --title=Download dialog --text=Starting... --auto-close --auto-kill
```

Now, suppose wget runs into an error. I need to inform the user that the download failed. Since the `$?` variable seems to have a value of `0` regardless of success or failure (perhaps because `$?` is storing zenity's exit status?), I can't tell if the download failed or succeeded.

How can I rectify the above described problem?

Comment: I think you need to write a script with intermediate files, so you can capture the intermediate statuses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say:

```
set -o pipefail
```

Saying so would cause `$?` to report the exit code of the last command in the pipeline to exit with a non-zero status.

Quoting from [The Set Builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> `pipefail`
>
> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all
>   commands in the pipeline exit successfully. This option is disabled by
>   default.

---

Additionally, the array `PIPESTATUS` would report the return code of all the commands in the pipeline.  Saying:

```
echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
```

would list all those.  For your example, it'd display 3 numbers, e.g.

1 0 0

if `wget` failed.

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables):

> PIPESTATUS
>
> An array variable (see Arrays) containing a list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground
>   pipeline (which may contain only a single command).